Wordpress - Switching from Timber Plugin 1.x to Composer Based Timber 1.x error Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Unable to register extension
I'm currently trying to switch ouf website version of Timber to its composer one. I managed to load the vendor and make the admin coming back without problem, by initializing Timber in the function.php file. But it seems there's an issue on our Starting site class, in the "add_to_twig" function to be more precise, and the throwed error don't help me that much ...
To add more context to this request, the site has been developed by someone else, using the plugin version of Timber, so it's kind of difficult to really point where is the issue there ...
All my custom post types and everything is showing correctly on the admin side, but when trying to render a page, it throws me this error : "Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Unable to register extension "Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension" as it is already registered. in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/dld/vendor/twig/twig/src/ExtensionSet.php on line 149"
I load this extension in the "add_to_twig" function, and this error is throwing with every filter I try to add this way. I searched to find if there was another place where this could be loaded, but I found none. (and it was working just fine with the plugin version ...)
It makes me think that it might be related to how I load Timber in my theme, but by comparing with the starter theme of Timber 1.x I can't see the problem.
Am I blind ?
I'm posting the function php code and the part of how the StarterSite file is integrated :
<?php

/**
 * Timber DLD Theme
 *
 * @package  WordPress
 * @subpackage  Timber
 * @since   Timber 0.1
 */

 $composer_autoload = __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
if ( file_exists( $composer_autoload ) ) {
    require_once $composer_autoload;
    $timber = new Timber\Timber();
}


if ( ! class_exists( 'Timber' ) ) {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', function() {
        echo '<div class="error"><p>Timber not activated. Make sure you activate the plugin in <a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'plugins.php#timber' ) ) . '">' . esc_url( admin_url( 'plugins.php' ) ) . '</a></p></div>';
    });

    add_filter('template_include', function( $template ) {
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/static/no-timber.html';
    });

    return;
}

/**
 * Sets the directories (inside your theme) to find .twig files
 */
Timber::$dirname = array( 'templates', 'views' );

/**
 * By default, Timber does NOT autoescape values. Want to enable Twig's autoescape?
 * No prob! Just set this value to true
 */
Timber::$autoescape = false;


include( "lib/DLDSite.php" );
new DLDSite();


And the extract of my StarterSite class :
<?php

/**
 * We're going to configure our theme inside of a subclass of Timber\Site
 * You can move this to its own file and include here via php's
 * include("MySite.php")
 */

class DLDSite extends Timber\Site {

  const VERSION = '1.2.1';
  const IS_PROD = 'production';

  /** Add timber support. */
  public function __construct() {
    add_action('after_setup_theme', [$this, 'theme_supports']);
    add_filter('timber/context', [$this, 'add_to_context']);
    add_filter('timber/twig', [$this, 'add_to_twig']);
    add_action('init', [$this, 'hide_editor']);
    add_action('init', [$this, 'register_taxonomies']);
    add_action('init', [$this, 'register_post_types']);
    add_action( 'init', [$this, 'disable_emojis'] );
    add_action('acf/init', [$this, 'register_acf_options_pages']);

    add_action('parse_query', [$this, 'no_nopaging_functionality_index']);

    add_filter('post_type_archive_title', [$this, 'functionality_archive_title_filter'], 11, 3);
    add_filter('bcn_breadcrumb_title', [$this, 'homepage_title_filter'], 10, 3);
    
    add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation', 'gf_check_uppercase_email' );
    add_filter('http_request_timeout', function ($timeout) {
      $newtimeout = 10;
      return $newtimeout;
    });

    foreach(get_field_object('field_5d7a40723c983')['choices'] as $choices){
      do_action( 'wpml_register_single_string', 'acfcustom', 'manquement choices - '.$choices, $choices );
    }
    add_action( 'save_post_sanction', array($this, 'invalidate_sanction_transient') );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'addSanctionUpdateMenu' );
    
    if (self::IS_PROD) {
      // Patch Gravity Forms for jquery async/defer issue
      
      add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'add_theme_sources'], 20);
    } else {
      add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'add_theme_sources'], 20);
    }

    parent::__construct();
  }
//...

/** This is where you can add your own functions to twig.
   *
   * @param string $twig get extension.
   */
  public function add_to_twig($twig) {
    $twig->addExtension( new Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension() );
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('remove_suggestion_and_loop', array( $this, 'remove_suggestion_and_loop' )));
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('remove_suggestion_and_loop_autoplay', array( $this, 'remove_suggestion_and_loop_autoplay' )));
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('remove_suggestion_and_loop_autoplay_popup', array( $this, 'remove_suggestion_and_loop_autoplay_popup' )));
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('embed_video_all_params', array( $this, 'embed_video_all_params' )));
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('shuffle', array( $this, 'shuffle' )));
    return $twig;
  }


The file is quite long so I juste put an extract here. I have more custom function here, but it's mostly function that add new items to menu or option in admin, so it shouldn't interfere with Timber (and it's working with the plugin version so ...)
I'm truely sorry if the error is obvious, but after trying for hours to make this work, I don't have any idea.
The full error message is : "Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Unable to register extension "Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension" as it is already registered. in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/dld/vendor/twig/twig/src/ExtensionSet.php on line 149 LogicException: Unable to register extension "Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension" as it is already registered. in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/dld/vendor/twig/twig/src/ExtensionSet.php on line 149". When I remove the StringLoaderExtension from "add_to_timber", the next filter I'm trying to load triggers this error and etc. whith each one of them.
More information about the site :
I'm running Wordpress V. 6.4.1 PhP 8.0
I have deactivated the plugin version of Timber before trying to activate the composer one.
I have some plugins like Gravity Forms, WPML or ACF, and they should be up to date (or 2-3 weeks old at most)
Thank you !

Can you log how many times the function add_to_twig is actually called?

Hmmm it's strange, when trying to var_dump from whithin the add_to_twig function or directly inside my starter class construct__ function, the var_dump is showing twice, as if I was trying to initiate my starting class more than once

You can/should track where the extra initialization comes from then - Have a look at this question/answer in order to find out where the extra call comes from

Okay, I might have found the culprit ... whithin the code I received, there were several use of new StartingClass() to be able to use methods on it and fetch content quickly. It works well with the plugin version, but I guess it doesn't with the composer based one ... My template are loading almost well now, but I guess I have to adapt the code. Thank you for the hint !

I think I found the culprit. In the code I received when I got the website from dev, there was several instance where a new StartingClass was defined, to make it possible to make quick request to use whithin templates.
Something like this :
$startingClass = new StartingClass();
$myVar = $startingClass->startingClassFunction();

When removing every reference to this, the template is loading fine (except for the part that was queried by the code above). My guess is that it was calling my starting class construct function each time it was used so yes, the extension (and everything else) was indeed loaded more than once.
It's quite strange it worked with the plugin version and not the composer version of Timber, but at least I can progress now.
